# Align JavaFX MenuItem Text on Center

Tags: java, javafx, text-alignment, text-align

I am trying to change the alignment of the below custom `MenuItem` text to the center using css but i can't achieve it and i get the following:

Using as text`Label` and the mouse not hovering above the `LabelMenuItem`:

[image]

Using as text `common` and the mouse hovers on the `LabelMenuItem`:

[image]

Image 3 [**The problem is that the Label width is smaller than the ContextMenu width** ]:

[image]

As you can see it is in the `Left` side . I have tried everything using css but it just doesn't want to change it's position

---

**What i want to achieve?**

I need to add Labels above some `ContextMenu` `MenuItems` . I achieved that but now i need the `-Text-alignment-` of that Labels to be on the center.

From css analyzer this property is by default `LEFT`
[image]

---

CSS code(**UPDATED,showing the label width problem**):

```
/*******************************************************************************

*                           Label-Menu-Item                            *

******************************************************************************/

.label-menu-item .label{
     -fx-text-alignment:center; 
}

.label-menu-item .label .text{
     -fx-text-alignment:center; 
}


/* When the Label-Menu-Item is disabled [Always it is cause i don't want the user to be able to click it] */
.label-menu-item:disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
    -fx-border-color:transparent white white white;
    -fx-cursor:default;
}

.label-menu-item:disabled:hover{
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}

.label-menu-item:disabled .label {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
    -fx-font-size:10.0;
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
    -fx-text-fill:white;
    -fx-text-alignment:center; 
}

.label-menu-item:disabled:hover .label {
    -fx-background-color: firebrick;
}
```

---

LabelMenuItem.java:

```
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;

/**
 * @author GOXR3PLUS
 *
 */
public class LabelMenuItem extends MenuItem {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param text
     *            The Text of The Menu Item
     * 
     */
    public LabelMenuItem(String text) {
    setText(text);
    setDisable(true);
    getStyleClass().clear();
    getStyleClass().add("label-menu-item");
    }

}
```

Comment: Trying to make the `MenuItem Label Width == ContextMenu Width `It seems to be an issue with css `-fx-pref-width:infinity` [ https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096649 ] , it is saying resolved but when i add infinity the contextmenu blows up ( not showing nothing ) :)

Comment: @James_D Can you provide some help ? :) I will be forever glad..

Answer (score 1):

if you try this:

```
.label-menu-item .label{
       //and here
      -fx-text-alignment:center; 
}

.label-menu-item .label .text{
      //and here
      -fx-text-alignment:center; 
}
```

instead of this:

```
.menu-item .label{
       //and here
      -fx-text-alignment:center; 
}

.menu-item .label .text{
      //and here
      -fx-text-alignment:center; 
}
```

does it work?

If not, maybe the `Label` just doesn't expand until the right border (i.e. has exactly the size of the text, so a different alignment doesn't change anything)? Then try to change the width of the `Label`.

Comment: `I updated the question using your css code and some more . As you can see from the second image the width of the **Label** is the same as of the ContextMenu :)` .

Comment: If you try it programmatically, just as a test, does it work then? I mean: `label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.Center);`

Comment: `MenuItem` has not such a method... I am extending `MenuItem` , `Label` can not be added to a `ContextMenu`.

Comment: In the css, you're applying the hover color to the whole label-menu-item, not just to the label. If you apply it only to the label, does the color also fill until the right border?

Comment: I have tried also building a `MenuButton` and checking it from the `SceneBuilder`, the text is going to center or right . But the Text from the `PopUpMenu ContextMenu` still is on left . Very strange...

Comment: Ouh the width of the `Label` is smaller than the `ContextMenu` width , i have added an image which shows it ... how to make the label grow to same width as the `contextMenu` ? :)

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this.. maybe as a dirty hack, add some spaces to the text, but I know that's an ugly solution.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with css `-fx-pref-width:infinity` [ https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096649 ] , it is saying resolved but when i add infinity the contextmenu blows up ( not showing nothing ) :)